# selenium4 can't connect to chrome on localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm going nuts trying to connnect in Selenium4 to Chrome instance on a localhost.
I invoked chrome from bash using

```
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=6666 --user-data-dir=/Users/h/Desktop/MY/chrome-profile
```

and next i tried to connect from Selenium4

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



# opt = Options()
# opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:6666")

# opt.add_argument("debuggerAddress", "localhost:6666") 
# opt.add_debuggerAddress("localhost:6666") 
# opt.add_debugger_address("localhost:6666") 
# web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)


# chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:6666")

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
# driver.get('https://www.google.com')


path = '/Users/h/Desktop/MY/webdrivers/chrome/105.0.5195.52/chromedriver'

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opt)

# service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
# driver.get('https://www.example.com/')

service = ChromeService(executable_path=path, port=6666) # i tried with local path and ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.example.com/')
```

i think i tried all possible options:

- prepending http:// to localhost throws an error,
- using chrome_options=chrome_options throws a deprecation warning, pointing i should use >options=<, and seems to have no effect on the browser in localhost,
- trying to launch webdriver from a local file, and currently suggested ChromeDriverManager. Both work. Until i want to specify options.

i also looped through the example i found on ~20 websites, incl. github bug reports - where people claim their code worked until VSCode upgraded.

I guess my question is - is there anything wrong with how i try to pass the chrome options, or did i actually encounter a bug ?

======
Edit:
that is a full error trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 29>()
     22 # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opt)
     23 
     24 # service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
     25 # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
     26 # driver.get('https://www.wp.pl/')
     28 service = ChromeService(executable_path=path, port=6666) #at this line you can use your ChromeDriverManager
---> 29 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
     30 driver.get('https://www.example.com/')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:69, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     66 if not service:
     67     service = Service(executable_path, port, service_args, service_log_path)
---> 69 super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
     70                  port, options,
     71                  service_args, desired_capabilities,
     72                  service_log_path, service, keep_alive)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py:92, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
     89 self.service.start()
     91 try:
---> 92     super().__init__(
     93         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     94             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     95             browser_name=browser_name, vendor_prefix=vendor_prefix,
     96             keep_alive=keep_alive, ignore_proxy=_ignore_proxy),
     97         options=options)
     98 except Exception:
     99     self.quit()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:270, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    268 self._authenticator_id = None
    269 self.start_client()
--> 270 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:363, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    361 w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
    362 parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps}
--> 363 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    364 if 'sessionId' not in response:
    365     response = response['value']

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:428, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    426 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    427 if response:
--> 428     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    429     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    430         response.get('value', None))
    431     return response

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:207, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    205     value = response['value']
    206 if isinstance(value, str):
--> 207     raise exception_class(value)
    208 if message == "" and 'message' in value:
    209     message = value['message']

WebDriverException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you are not making import of webdriver, and you have named Service as ChromeService.

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
 from selenium import webdriver
```

Then avoid to pass the port with Options and use the option port of Service (now called ChromeServie)

```
# chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:6666")
service = ChromeService(executable_path="chromedriver", port=6666) #at this line you can use your ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.example.com/')
```

Comment: i actually imported webdriver - for some reason it got commented?
I re-run the code as you described it, and still get an error. You can see the full error in my question, above

Comment: i cannot see the message of webdriver exception on last line of ur error log, and i tryed your code, works perfect on my pc. Please share the `WebDriverException: Message: `

Comment: that's the thing - there is no message. its empty :)

Comment: i think you found a issue, it can be about your something that is defferent in your machine or really an issue, in any case, please post a issue to the github project of selenium, please if you solve the issue, ppost that here too, so you can help other people

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, though i have to say it was more luck than knowing how to.
The documentation is super lacking :(

If anyone is looking for how to take control of already running browser,
specifically with selenium4 and python, here goes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:6666")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options = chrome_options)

driver.get('http://example.com')
```